# Show alert when checkbox check

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on getting the data from php and populate the check box but i want the jquery so that i can show each selected value when checkbox checked

code

```
<input type='checkbox' class='messageCheckbox'  name='emergency2[]' value='$rowspecial[category_id]' $checked $disableattr> $rowspecial[category_name]
```

Comment: So add a change event.

Comment: how can i add it can you let me know

Comment: Suggest you study some tutorials about form control events

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but it uses jquery and checkboxes and a good place to start http://jsfiddle.net/4DqXv/3

Answer (score -2):

add an onClick attribute to the input.

```
<input type='checkbox' ... onClick="func">
```

Comment: What you have shown would do absolutely nothing